# How to check user authentication?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In the following code I want to buy if the user has entered the username and password correctly. I have this, but it doesn't work.

```
else{
            conexion.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = ?', [user], async (error, results)=>{
                if( results.length == 0 || ! ((results[0].pass)) ){
                    res.render('login', {
                        alert: true,
                        alertTitle: "Error",
                        alertMessage: "Usuario y/o Password incorrectas",
                        alertIcon:'error',
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        timer: false,
                        ruta: 'login'    
                    })
```

Comment: the is no password checks. What is "doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: You are not comparing password in your query.